# Is there a way to calculate the area of a building in OSMNX?

Tags: polygon, area, surface, building, osmnx

Let me start of by stating that I'm new to programming in Python and working with OSMNX.

I have the building footprints saved in a Geodataframe as:
`gdf = ox.geometries_from_polygon(P, tags={'building':True})  # Geo dataframe for buildings`

If I open this geodataframe, I see the polygons that are used for the buildings (among many other things). My question is, how can I add another column that will be able to calculate the area for each building from this polygon?

Help is much appreciated :) !

Comment: Yes there is. Have you read OSMnx's documentation and usage examples? What did they have to say about this?

Comment: Hi Geoff! thank you for your response! I checked and already found the answer. I did this: `gdf= gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:32633'})
gdf["area"] = gdf['geometry'].area`